# Bit manuplating

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I want to get input for example 0xaabbccdd and convert it to DDCCBBAA or convert the input oxf0f0 t0 F0F0. The next code that i wrote managed to convert f0f0f0 to 0f0f0f.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

     int number;

     scanf("%x",&number);

     if(number > 1){
     number = (~number);
     printf("Number hex is %x decimal is (%d) ",number,number);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For people to help, please give the output and explain what is or is not what you wanted.

Comment: So basically you want to swap endianness?

Comment: You don't appear to have included a question in your post. Additionally, you don't appear to have included enough information here for a meaningful question to be extracted from your confusing statement. Please clarify your inquiry.

Comment: sorry your right. I wanted to ask what the most practical why to do  it and understand it. I want the input 0xAABB and convert to BBAA

Answer (score 0):

It's not really obvious whether you want to know the best way to do this in a practical application, or whether you are just trying to work out how it works.

Assuming the former:

- If this is for network/host byte order, use the `htonl` and `ntohl` for 32 bit quantities, and `htons` and `ntohs` for shorts.
- If this is not for network/host byte order, we can steal^Wreuse their code. When a swap is needed, these use the `__bswap32` and `__bswap16` functions. These are made available through the `bswap_32` and `bswap_16` interfaces - just `#include <byteswap.h>`

Assuming you are interested in how this works, look at `/usr/include/bits/byteswap.h` on a Linux machine, and you'll see optimised byteswapping routines. Here's one:

```
#define __bswap_constant_32(x) \
     ((((x) & 0xff000000) >> 24) | (((x) & 0x00ff0000) >>  8) |               \
      (((x) & 0x0000ff00) <<  8) | (((x) & 0x000000ff) << 24))
```

which is the obvious way to do it.

There's also a neat trick you can do with XOR to swap groups of bits around. See: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#SwappingBitsXOR

Comment: I'm learning so i want to learn how it works and practical way to do it

Comment: One thing you need to be very careful about is SIGN EXTENSION. When you're right-shifting an unsigned (char, short, int, long, long long, etc), the bits to the left of your previously-most-significant bit are always filled with zeroes. When you right-shift a signed number that is negative (that is, with the most significant bit set to 1), all the new bits on the left will be set to one. When byte swapping, this is undesirable. So... shift first, THEN mask off the bits you don't care about. Don't do it the other way around or you're asking for trouble.

Comment: Actually, when right-shifting a signed negative integer, what happens to the sign bit is implementation defined. Your implementation may choose to preserve the sign or not.

Comment: Fair enough,  Elchonon Edelson, but I've never seen one that doesn't preserve the sign.